# Can't find assembly System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Tags: powershell

Can't find assembly System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

When loading assembly

```
Add-Type -Path .\H.Hooks.dll
```

H.Hooks.dll is a local dll-.net file.
What are the possible issues?

Comment: What framework targeting options was `H.Hooks.dll` compiled with? From the error message it sounds like it was compiled specifically for .NET 5 or newer, and you're probably trying to load it in Windows PowerShell (which runs on .NET Framework 4.5)

Comment: Dll was compiled for .net version 5.0. Download version compiled against 4.5.1 and it worked. Thx